# trouble of ruby plugin of eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I'm trying to install RDT on my Eclipse Indigo on my Macbook Pro. Installation seems ok, I can create a new ruby project. But the problem is that in Ruby Explorer:

```
Could not create the view: org/eclipse/search/internal/ui/text/ResourceTransferDragAdapter
```

I googled this, there were many people reported same problem, but nobody provided a solution.

Could anybody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide details of your installation? Eclipse Indigo is an older version of Eclipse, and RDT is not very active, so there are chances that the installation does not fit well together. There are different download options available from http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/install.php, so explain which one you have used.

Comment: @mliebelt Thanks for you comment. I just start to learn Ruby today. I want to create a Ruby development environment on my Macbook Pro. If RDT is not active yet, could you please recommend something else? My Eclipse Indigo also has Android ADT and Python Pydev installed, I don't want to break those plugins.